# Data binding adapter in android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I got this error while using binding adapter

"To use data binding annotations in Kotlin, apply the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin in your module's build.gradle"

```
@BindingAdapter("app:backgroundColor")
fun changeColor(view: View, color:MyColors) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(
        when (color) {
            MyColors.RED -> Color.RED
            MyColors.YELLOW -> Color.YELLOW
            MyColors.BLUE -> Color.BLUE
        }
    )
}
```

I try to solve it, but I don't know what is kapt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it:
Add this code into build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```